# Change colour of widget depending on index/variable

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement

I have a custom BottomNav bar and successfully changing the background colour depending on the selectedIndex. I'm doing this via a ternary statement:

```
backgroundColor: selectedIndex == 0
      ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 52, 35)
      : const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 13, 52),
```

Now I've added a 3rd screen, I want to set up an if statement along these lines:

```
backgroundColor: 
      if (selectedIndex == 0)
      {const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 52, 35);}
      if (selectedIndex == 1)
      {const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 13, 52);}
      if (selectedIndex == 2)
      {const Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 0, 54);},
```

It may just be a simple syntax issue - I'm new to Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function like this:

```
Color getBackgroundColor(int selectedIndex){
   if (selectedIndex == 0){
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 52, 35);
   }else if (selectedIndex == 1){
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 13, 52);
   }else {
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 0, 54);
   }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
backgroundColor: getBackgroundColor(selectedIndex),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate method with `switch`.

```dart
Color getColor(int selectedIndex) {
  switch (selectedIndex) {
    case 0:
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 52, 35);

    case 1:
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 13, 52);

    case 2:
      return const Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 0, 54);

    default:
      return Colors.green;
  }
}
```

And use

```dart
backgroundColor: getColor(selectedIndex),
```

More about [switch-and-case](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually nest ternary expressions to get what you want, like:

```
backgroundColor: selectedIndex == 0
  ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 52, 35)
  : selectedIndex == 1
    ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 13, 52)
    : const Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 0, 54),
```

Although I'd recommend Yeasin Sheikh's answer more, especially if you want to add even more indexes

Comment: Interesting! thanks Ivo

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to use a `Map<int, Color>` and use the index as a `key` for the map:

```dart
Color getColor(int selectedIndex) {
  return const <int, Color>{
        0: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 52, 35),
        1: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 13, 52),
        2: Color.fromARGB(255, 87, 0, 54),
      }[selectedIndex] ?? Colors.green; // default value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers here are great. The best practice would be using `switch-case`.

I'd also like to add a solution that changes color based on index. It's not flexible with choosing the exact color that you want but its useful for contrasts  between lists.

```
 int red = (selectedIndex + 30) % 256; 
 int green = (selectedIndex + 30) % 256; 
 int blue = (selectedIndex * 30) % 256; 
 Color modifiedColor = Color.fromARGB(255, red, green, blue);

backgroundColor: modifiedColor;
```